# Inserting into std::map while iterating over it?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a Map over which I iterate like this:

```
std::map<unsigned int, GameObject *>::iterator itr = _gameObjects.begin();
    while (itr != _gameObjects.end())
    {
        itr->second->Update();
        itr++;
    }
```

Update() might insert an element into the map or even remove one from it, but it doesn't necessarily do any of the two.
It obviously doesn't work like that. Is there a way it can be done?

Comment: What keys can `Update()` insert in to? What behaviour do you want if a new element gets inserted to before the current position of the iterator?

Comment: Can `Update()` remove itself?

Comment: @hmjd right now it could, yes.

Comment: @Mankarse I don't get your first question, sorry. Within Update() it is possible that a completely new key-value pair is inserted into the map. For your second one, it doesn't really matter if it's Update() is called or not

Comment: @tschaei: My question was poorly phrased, but your answer pretty much covers it (;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [`std::map::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

From [`std::map::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> No iterators or references are invalidated.

From [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> No iterators or references are invalidated.

If `Update()` does not remove itself, then the code is legal. If `Update()` does, then it is not. `Update()` would be required to inform the calling code if it removed itself, either setting a flag or returning the next iterator (as suggested by [Attila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20322/attila)).

Comment: Thanks. This means I'll have to add a boolean _erase to my GameObject class which is set in Update() and let the loop handle the removal of elements.

Answer (score 2):

The `erase` function in STL usually returns an iterator to the next valid element (or `end()` if no  such element is available).  You could return this iterator from `Update` and re-assign it to `itr`