# Appending to a map in a foreach loop

Tags: c++

I have logic which is something like the following:

```cpp
std::map <cv::Point, bool, ComparisonStruct> m;
std::map <cv::Point, bool, ComparisonStruct> m2;

m = ... // assign some key values

for (auto &el : m) {
   // do some logic
   f(m); // <-- may append new key / values to m
   g(m2) // <--- may remove key/vals from m2
}
```

when I added the f logic, the for loop no longer terminates. Am I not allowed to do this? What is the cleanest way to set something like this up? I would have assumed you can do this, and that eventually el would be the new key/value appended from f.

The loop also doesnt terminiate if I try and `erase` from m2 by calling something like `m2.erase(p)` where `p` is a `cv::Point`

Comment: What is `Map`? is it a costume container or the STL `std::map` container?

Comment: it is std::map.

Comment: Is this a possible duplicate of the problem in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706511/inserting-into-stdmap-while-iterating-over-it

Comment: But if you look in that post, it says that inserting does not invalidate an iterator?

Comment: Even if I try and erase from a totally independent map, I have the same issue. I will add more information

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that if you ONLY remove from `m2` (lets say you never call `f(m)`, only call `g(m2)`) then the loop doesn't terminate?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better not add key/value to map in a loop when traversing it. This will make iterator not function proper.

A simple way to solve it is put key/value into a vector first and then transfer them to the map in another loop.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I not allowed to [append to a map in a foreach loop]?

You are allowed to do this.

> What is the cleanest way to set something like this up?

What you've done is fairly clean.

> would have assumed you can do this, and that eventually el would be the new key/value appended from f.

I see no reason to assume that does not happen. In fact, that is probably the reason why the loop doesn't end: Adding an element means that there is one more element to iterate. If every step you take, you add more steps that you need to take, then you will never reach the end of your steps.

So, if your intention is to infinitely insert more elements to the map while you iterate the elements that you keep inserting, then your program is correct. If that is not what you intended, then you need to think about what it is that you intend to do instead.

Comment: Are you allowed to remove? For example, if f(m) may remove an item from the map that hasnt been seen yet.

Comment: You are allowed to erase from the other map like in your example. You are also allowed to erase from the same map as long as you don't erase the element currently being iterated. Erasing the current element will result in undefined behaviour.